# Dynamic Charts in ActiveReports

Tags: vb.net-2010, activereports, componentone

I am currently developing a report using ActiveReport where there I need to display Charts.  The number of charts that will be displayed is dynamic based the data.... The report will be laied out somehting like this.

- Account Number/Name [group header]
- Some Account Details [details]
- Account Name & charts(s)(one for each detail line) [group footer]

As I said above, the contents of the details & charts could be different for each group.

I have read that that dynamic report creation had to be done in _ReportStart, but if I do that, I does the correct charts make it to the correct group (account number)??

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what exactly you want to do and what the problem is. As I understand there is a set of charts in the group footer and you want to hide and show some of them depending on the data.

If you only want to hide and show some of them, then you can create the report statically in the designer, and in the Format event of the GroupFooter Section, you can hide or show the charts accordingly.

However, if it is entirely unclear how many charts will be in the group footer, then you should use a subreport. Design a report that has a template for the charts you need and then place that subreport in the group footer of the parent report. Using a subreport will allow you to completely change the charts/controls for every group.

If you'd like additional help please comment and explain more about what exactly is in the charts and what is changing based on the data. It is difficult to give more detail without understanding more about what you're doing, what you've tried and what exact problems you've encountered.